# Regex which include substring and not include another

Tags: regex

I need regex which check if string contains `foo` and not contains `bar`
For example

```
foo - pass
something only with foo - pass
with foo and bar - fail
without fu but bar - fail
abracadabra - fail
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

try this : `^(?!.*(bar)).*foo.*$`

Comment: exactly what is needed. Thank you